# Tool to expand one feature to align with another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, advanced-license-level

I have an island (grey) and ocean (blue). These are individual features in the same layer. There are several areas where the ocean feature does not meet the land.

I can create a map topology and use the Align Edge tool to fix the gaps on an individual basis, but I want to find one tool that will expand the surrounding polygon (blue) to meet the edge of the island polygon.

Is there a simple tool that exists for this, or another process within an edit session? I have an Advanced License so I would be very surprised if there is nothing like this.

[image]

Comment: Snap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 look at case III, it's almost *your* picture exactly.

Comment: Polygons to lines,lines to polygons,select ones outside original, make them blue. Merge, dissolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Fill Gaps (Production Mapping) tool works OK. It definitely takes a while to run, so I definition queried out to display just the polygons of interest. The tool requires an Advanced License and the Production Mapping extension must be checked on.

I was using just a single layer (all my features were in the one layer) and found the tool required me to choose the Fill Option FILL_BY_ORDER to run .. a bit odd since there's nothing to order when there's only one layer involved. Anyways, it worked, much faster than editing vertices, reshaping features or aligning edges would.

EDIT: this tool may need to be run twice to actually fill all the gaps!

Comment: 1/3

It can be unnerving to run this tool outside of an edit session, but it actually runs better that way, I have found.
I ran it on a single layer within a .gdb, which is probably important. You should do this too. Also note that I didn't checkmark the Fill Unenclosed Gaps option.
When you run this tool outside of an editing session, it will produce a bunch of feature layers, including an UnenclosedGaps_FC (and a Union and Intersect feature layer which I removed right away).

Comment: 2/3


You can then start an edit session (select the layer that has the gaps as your layer to edit), then select the many small features in the feature layer just created (UnenclosedGaps_FC), copy them, turn off UnenclosedGaps_FC,  paste the small gap features into the layer, then while they are still selected, add to the selection your big polygon(s) you want to join these gaps to, then Editor > Merge..  
(Because the copied small gap features come from a temporary feature layer, they will all have names like 875739036  that are easy to tell from the layer you want  to merge them to.)

Comment: 3/3

Once merged, you are done! I like this method because you more more control over what large polygons your gap gets merged to. And it also seems to run much better than it does when you're in an edit session.